# ¿Es posible conectar dos UdpClient al mismo socket local?

Tags: vb.net

Necesito tener un thread escuchando en un puerto `UDP` especifico a designar por el usuario y los `ACK` deben ser enviados desde el mismo puerto al puerto desde el que se esta escuchando en el servidor local pero al presionar un botón en la GUI del server; es decir no puedo responder en el momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando intento responder, al estar el primer socket Bindeado a este puerto especifico no me permite crear el nuevo UdpClient para enviar una respuesta a la ultima IP.

Ya probe poniendo el valor

```
.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
```

del primer socket, el que escucha, así como

```
.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
```

He probado una docena de ejemplos que encontré pero todos tienen el mismo problema, para recibir andan perfectos, pero cuando se agrega código para un segundo socket ya no funciona.

No sé que más hacer.

El código siguiente envía y recibe pero sólo a la primera IP que se conecta. Probé desconectar luego de enviar pero me da error 100057.

```vb
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading

#Region "UDP Receive variables"
    Public RemoteIpEndPoint As New System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 5000)
    Public ThreadReceive As System.Threading.Thread
    Dim SocketNO As Integer
    Dim UdpOpen As Boolean = False
    Dim DstPort As Integer = 0
    Private permission As SocketPermission
    Dim LastIpRemota As String = ""
    Dim LastPort As String = ""
#End Region

#Region "UDP Send variables"
    Dim GLOIP As IPAddress
    Dim GLOINTPORT As Integer
    Dim bytCommand As Byte() = New Byte() {}
    Dim MyUdpClient As New UdpClient()
#End Region

Private Sub StartUdpReceiveThread(ByVal Port As Integer)
      Dim UdpAlreadyOpen As Boolean = False

      Try
          'If Not UdpOpen Then
          permission = New SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Accept, TransportType.Udp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts)
          permission.Demand()
          MyUdpClient = New UdpClient()
          MyUdpClient.ExclusiveAddressUse = False
          MyUdpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, True)
          ''****** Codigo agregado para hacer Bind ******
          Dim LocalEnPoint As EndPoint
          Dim LocalIP As System.Net.IPAddress
          LocalIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0")
          LocalEnPoint = New System.Net.IPEndPoint(LocalIP, Port)
          MyUdpClient.Client.Bind(LocalEnPoint)
          ''***********************************************

          UdpAlreadyOpen = True

          '  End If

          ThreadReceive = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf UdpReceive)
          ThreadReceive.IsBackground = True

          ThreadReceive.Start()
          UdpOpen = True

          If UdpAlreadyOpen Then 'Solo se imprime la primera vez
              PrintLog(String.Format("Puerto UDP {0} abierto, esperando datos...", Port.ToString))
          End If
      Catch ex As Exception
          PrintLog(ex.Message)
          PrintLog(ex.StackTrace)
      End Try
End Sub

Private Sub UdpReceive()
    Dim ACK As String = ""
    Dim receiveBytes As [Byte]() = MyUdpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint) ' aqui se traba al salir, queda esperando datos fuera del codigo

    DstPort = RemoteIpEndPoint.Port
    IpRemota(RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString)

    Dim BitDet As BitArray
    BitDet = New BitArray(receiveBytes)
    Dim strReturnData As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)

    PrintLog("From: " & IpRemotaLbl.Text & ":" & PuertoEscuchaLbl.Text & " - " & strReturnData)
    ACK = "OK 12345" & vbCrLf  'AnswersProcessor(strReturnData)

    If ACK.Length > 7 Then
        MyUdpClient.Connect(RemoteIpEndPoint)
        MyUdpClient.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ACK), ACK.Length)
        'MyUdpClient.Client.Disconnect(True) 'Da error 10057
    End If

    If UdpOpen Then
        StartUdpReceiveThread(5000)
    End If
    ' MyUdpClient.Client.LingerState = True

End Sub

Private Sub UdpSend(ByVal txtMessage As String)
 'Esta rutina da error porque el puerto ya esta siendo usado por el otro UdpClient

    Dim pRet As Integer
    GLOIP = IPAddress.Parse(IpRemotaLbl.Text)
    GLOINTPORT = PuertoEscuchaLbl.Text
    MyUdpClient.Connect(GLOIP, DstPort)
    bytCommand = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(txtMessage)
    pRet = MyUdpClient.Send(bytCommand, bytCommand.Length)
    'Console.WriteLine("No of bytes send " & pRet)
    PrintLog("No of bytes send " & pRet)
End Sub
```

Puede que sobre alguna variable porque ya lo modifiqué un montón de veces.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, por favor agrega tu codigo para que sea mas facil entender tu pregunta.

Comment: @Gemasoft Gracias por leer, ya agregue el código fuente. Solo puse la parte UDP así que puede que haya alguna funciona que escribe en la GUI pero no esta declarada en el código adjunto.

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener ni idea de vb.net, creo que estás enfocando mal el problema.

¿ porqué no usas el thread que escucha también para enviar ?

Ese primer thread (al que llamaremos SERVER) *deberia* de escuchar en el puerto UDP que indiques y *en otro socket* o *tuberia* o *puerto* o como quiera que lo llamen en vb.net, en el que escuchar las órdenes de un segundo thread, que será el encargado de la GUI (a ese thread lo llamamos GUI).

Cuando se pulse el botón, GUI manda un paquete a SERVER, que a su vez envia los datos que quieras por el puerto en cuestión.

Comment: Eso es lo que quería hacer desde un principio, el tema es que el socket que escucha, una vez que recibe datos, queda enlazado con la primera IP e ignora paquetes de otras IP que apuntan al mismo puerto. El código que agregue hace eso. Todo esto ya lo tenia funcionando pero en Windows XP con dos sockets(no es el código adjunto), uno que escucha y otro momentáneo que envía; cuando mude todo a Windows 7 dejo de funcionar(no es el código que puse) porque saltaba un error que me decía que no podía enviar porque el socket ya estaba siendo usado, es decir recibía, pero no podía responder.

Comment: Es mas si uso el ejecutable que genera el compilador actualmente en Windows 7 en Windows XP no me da error, en Windows 7 si. Se ve que Windows 7 debe tener alguna capa de soft que esta impidiendo usar el mismo puerto por dos sockets aunque sean de la misma aplicación.

Comment: Vale, ya te digo que de vb.net, ni idea. Pero ese comportamiento del socket es raro en UDP. Lo único que se me ocurre decirte es que instales la misma versión del framework .net (si eran distintas, que seguro que ya lo has hecho). Si el W7 necesite permisos especiales para UDP, entonces no recibirias nada. No se que decirte, lo siento. Suerte.